Replace HDD in a Raid 1
I'm new to Raid configuration.
I have a server with Raid 1 ( 2 HDD )
Several days ago i've noticed a message during server startup that 1 one HDD is almost dead.
I've entered on raid configuration and 1 one HDD is with red status.
Now i have removed this hard drive , and after that if i turned on the server everything run ok with other HDD.
But i want to replace the damaged hard drive with another one.
i have 2 problems :

I can find another HDD with the same size , but not the same brand

If i put the new hdd on server , is RAID fixed automatically and the new HDD cloned automatically or i should do something ?



Even if it wasn’t the same size the RAID would only use the size up to the smallest disk. If the RAID goes into a repair state is dependent on many factors you haven’t shared. In either case, the new HDD is required, there is no way around it
